# How to integrate chartjs-chart-financial with chart js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2, candlesticks

I'd like to use `chartjs-chart-financial` to plot a 'candlestick' chart. However, `chartjs-chart-financial` isn't published to npm yet. I run an `npm install` followed by `gulp build` in the directory that has the cloned repo from https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-chart-financial. I see chartjs-chart-financial.js in the `dist` folder after it has built. However, I'm clueless as to how to get this to integrate with the base `chart.js` library, so that I can specify a `type: candlestick` on my Chart. I haven't been able to come across any examples where this is demonstrated..

I'm currently using `react-chartjs-2` as a wrapper around `chart.js` since I'm working in React:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Chart from '../node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart';

class Financial extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const ctx = this.myRef.current;
        this.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Test',
                    data: [12, 20, 15],
                    backgroundColor: 'gray'
                }]
            }
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <canvas ref={this.myRef}/>
        );
    }
}

export default Financial;
```

As you can see, I'm rendering a sample chart with type `bar` for now. I'd like to be able to use type 'candlestick' instead, along with its associated dataset.

I'd appreciate any help!!

Comment: If you see `chartjs-chart-financial` in your `node_modules` directory, then you should be able to import it just like any other npm package

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! The issue is that `chartjs-chart-financial` is a UMD module in the form of an immediately-invoked function. In their only example, they just insert the reference to the file in the `<script>` tag: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-chart-financial/ . I'm not sure how to translate this into 'invoking' the IIFE within my React code.

Comment: To anyone who might be reading this in the future - you need access to the file `chartjs-chart-financial.js` after it has been built. This will usually be in your `dist` directory. If you're using something like webpack, make sure that you set the configurations so that it ignores this file and doesn't transpile it down to es5. You can then simply use this by an import statement: `import './my-path/chartjs-chart-financial';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package in your app without NPM repository. Only need this simple "trick" in your package.json:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "chartjs-chart-financial": "github:chartjs/chartjs-chart-financial"
  }
```

**Important note:** The GitHub repository must have a package.json file!